# How to properly customize UITabBar and UITabBarItem on iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am googling around so much, but nowhere I find a *straight* and *consolidated* answer.

I want to customize my`UITabBarController` such that:

1. the `UITabBar` itself is completely black
2. the text color of the item titles is white in *non-highlighted* state
3. the text color of the item titles is red in *highlighted* state
4. Use multicolored icons in the tab bar

#### 1. Turn `UITabBar` black

I am guessing I need to use the `UIAppearance` API for this, and actually I was able to turn the `UITbarBar` black using: `[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`.

#### 2. and 3. Modify color of item titles

However, the color of the text items doesn't seem to do what I want, after googling around, the following solutions made sense to me, but it only changes the *non-highlighted* state to white, *highlighted* stays white as well...

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
NSDictionary *highlightedTitleAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : titleHighlightedColor};
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:highlightedTitleAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

#### 4. Multicolored items

About the multicolored icons, so far by approach was to simply set the icons in *Storyboards* like this:

[image]

But this doesn't do what I want, it only shows the whole icon in grey when the item is *not* selected. When the item is selected, the icon completely disappears.

This is the original icon:

[image]

This is how it looks when the item is *not* selected:

[image]

And here it is in the selected stated, as mentioned the icon completely disappears:

[image]

So, my question is how precisely I can achieve the above mentioned requirements. What am I currently missing? Am I better off doing everything in code than in Storyboards?

**Note: I am targeting iOS versions greater than 7.0, so please include any version specific information if the behaviour differs between iOS 7 and iOS 8.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. As far as I know there is no difference for the different iOS versions.
I solved it programmatically like this:

1. Turning the bar color black works as following (You already said it) (in AppDelegate):

   `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()`
2. To set the color of the title for the different states, I used this code (in AppDelegate):

   ```
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName!: UIColor.redColor()], forState:.Selected)
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName!: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Normal)
   ```
3. (and 4.) You can achieve the different item colors, multicolored icons and different item colors for the different states, by setting the image programmatically and change the rendering mode (`imageWithRenderingMode:`) to `UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal`, this looks as following (do this in the first view controller class for all your view controllers):

   ```
   var recentsItem = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
   var recentsItemImage = UIImage(named:"recents.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
   var recentsItemImageSelected = UIImage(named: "recentsSelected.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
   recentsItem.image = recentsItemImage
   recentsItem.selectedImage = recentsItemImageSelected
   ```

I hope this helps, if you have any following questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: I actually had the right approach for _3._ as well, only my mistake was that I chose `UIControlStateHighlighted` instead of `UIControlStateSelected`, thanks for pointing that out! :) Also, the hint about `UIImageRenderingMode` was really helpful!

Comment: About #2 : We should remember that `UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes` will only work to customize `.font` `.foregroundColor` and `.shadow` and not the other keys (cf. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaritem/1616414-settitletextattributes)

Answer (score 6):

Solution provided by smudis is great and because I don't have enough reputation to comment I decided to post the 3rd part of smudis' solution in Objective-C, in case it might help somebody:

To get a reference of the tabBar type the above code into AppDelegate's method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tb = tbc.tabBar;
```

Then the image adjustment can be done as follows:

```
for (UITabBarItem *tbi in tb.items) {
    tbi.selectedImage = [tbi.selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tbi.image = [tbi.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
```