# (Swift) selected tabBar Color?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor, selected

I already know how to set tabBar's "barTintColor". What I want to know is how to set a specific color to selected tabBar(Like in the pic the tabBar which is selected is having dark pink color). Just like that.Thanks in advance :)

[image: Tab Bar]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly customize UITabBar and UITabBarItem on iOS 7 and iOS 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144220/how-to-properly-customize-uitabbar-and-uitabbaritem-on-ios-7-and-ios-8)

Comment: are you looking for an option to make a custom uicolor like: 1 let myColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.2, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1) ?

Comment: No. What I am looking for is how to change the background color of tabbar item in selected state as shown in pic

Comment: @Satachito thanx for the link you provided. It partially solved my problem on text color and I've updated my question. But still I'm not getting the solution for selected tabBar color

Comment: I think your answer is sublassing UITabBarViewController as described here: [How to change UITabBar Selection color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790746/how-to-change-uitabbar-selection-color/18996564#18996564)

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu I am looking for an answer in "Swift" not Objective-C

Comment: the commands are the same. just get rid of the [] syntax.

Comment: No kidding.  Any iOS developer who doesn't take the time to get at least somewhere familiar with both Objective-C and Swift is just making their life harder.  The frameworks are identical... the syntax is slightly different... if you can read Objective-C, you could have your solution quicker than posting a Swift question and demanding someone give you a Swift answer...

Comment: @nhgrif I am at beginner stage. just 4 months into it. I might not be as skilled as you are. Btw I have read somewhere that the feature I'm looking for has been deprecated , though m not sure. If you are so good with objective-c and swift both. Would have been better if you would have given the solution along with your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set background color of active tab bar item in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045147/set-background-color-of-active-tab-bar-item-in-swift)

Comment: isn't it dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790746/how-to-change-uitabbar-selection-color?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

**Change the tintColor**  (that's all you are allowed to do)

Make a subclass of UITabBarController, set it as the class of your UITabBarViewController:

```
class myOwnTBC: UITabBarController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar.tintColor = .blueColor()
  }
}
```

After more research following your comment:

I do believe, Apple does not want a developer to change the backgroundcolor of the UITabBar. Please see Apple's [Interface Guidelines concerning the TabBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html). I quote from it:

> A tab bar: 
>   Is translucent

I tried subclassing UITabBarItem and manipulate the background, which gave me the following Exception:

> Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar Controller is not allowed

**Solution?!**
You won't like it, but if you want to use a UITabBarController, you have to stick with the translucent preset.

**Workaround?**
The only workaround I can think of at the Moment is: Create your own navigation using your own UIView-Subclass. This will violate the Interface Guidelines anyways, but you can reach your Goal.

Comment: The code which you have mentioned will change the image color of tabBar(In my case I've set it to white). So it's not the solution m looking for.

Comment: I added information to my answer, although you might not like it :)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving so much time to it and giving some valuable information to me.. thanx :)