# iOS Change NavigationBar appearance throughout entire app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have multiple UINavigationController throughout my storyboard. Since I am using a tabbarcontroller every tab item has it's own UINavigationController embedded before it's ViewController.

I'd like to style all of these at the same time. Things that I have tried that work are going to a ViewControllers `ViewWillAppear` method and adding the following lines:

```
UINavigationBar *nav = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
nav.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
nav.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
nav.translucent = NO;
```

But then I'd have to do this for every tab item and every ViewController.

Also, doing the following in the AppDelegate did NOT work:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Specifically I am curious why using the appearance proxy doesn't work. I'm fairly new so if you give a solution involving custom UINavigationController or setting up a delegate please elaborate. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line too in your code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: Whoops! That did it! thanks @Nishant! I'll mark you the correct answer in a moment. While I have you here, how can I change the imageRenderingMode of a TabBarController if it's my initial view controller?

Comment: Thanks. Here is a good answer for this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27196023/1463604
If it doesn't work, i will need some of your code snippet that you might have implemented. You can add a new question for it and give me the link to it.